# SQL Lookup table where there are multiple incoming codes

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

SQL Lookup 
I need to build a lookup table that will allow for multiple ‘match from’  possibilities
Ie
Find a text code based on an incoming text from say Ohio or Vermont, having the possibility of others later. I also need history so if an Ohio code changes that can still be found by date without interfering with the current active code.

```
txtCode | OhioCode | VACode|  … future expansion

100A    | 567BR     | Thing |

100B    | 4FJEU    | 54DS  |
```

I could use a single table but that doesn’t seem very efficient.  With multiple tables, one for each state, future expansion seems more complicated but perhaps that is the way to go?  Whould I use a table to some how lookup tables?

So what are the best practices for doing something like this?

Comment: Separate columns for each state is NOT the best way to go. And multiple tables is even worse. If you do that you need 50 joins where only one is needed. But the biggest is here is that your question lacks enough detail to offer any solid advice.

Comment: Do you have a logical distinction between "active" and "historical" codes (like a column for the active ones?). I find if I have created columns with some distinct value in the name (ex: Ohio) then my design has gone wrong somewhere.

Comment: I have yet to build this table so I can add anything.  I am having dificulty finding a good way to do it!  I was thinking I would have 'ActivationDate' and an isActive flag.

Comment: What kind of detail are you looking for @Jacob H ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is txtCode?

The most standard way to do this is a normalized lookup with effective date timestamps.

```
 Txt_Code | State_Code | State_Value | Rec_Strt_Dt | Rec_End_Dt   | Current_Flag
 100A       OH           567BR         12/1/2000     12/03/9999     N
 100A       OH           NewValue      12/3/2000     12/31/9999     Y
 100A       VA           Thing         12/1/2000     12/31/9999     Y
 100B       OH           4FJEU         12/1/2000     12/31/9999     Y
 100B       VA           54DS          12/1/2000     12/31/9999     Y
```

It really does depend on the type of queries you'll be running though.
(and you'll likely want timestamps offset by 1 second for the effective dates)

Then you can index on state_code, txt_code + state_code, current_flag, etc...
Depending on what you're doing.

Comment: txtCode is what I want to find based on the incoming code which could be from various sources.

Comment: @GDutton So you're going to be asking questions like "What is the associated txtCode when Ohio is XXXX"?

Comment: In this example I would have the state_code and State_Value and would be looking for TXT_Code.  So I think this example works.

Comment: Yeah, this should work then. In that case it's common to create an index on state_code + state_value so the txt_code lookup will be efficient.

Answer (score 2):

A normalized approach would look something more like this. What I don't really understand though is your concept of "currently active code". Not sure what that means in relation to the data posted.

```
create table CodeLookup
(
    txtCode varchar(10) not null
    , CodeValue varchar(10) not null
    , StateCode char(2) not null
    , DateCreated datetime not null
)

insert CodeLookup values
('100A', '567BR', 'OH', getdate())
, ('100A', 'Thing', 'VA', getdate())
, ('100B', '4FJEU', 'OH', getdate())
, ('100B', '54DS', 'VA', getdate())


select *
from CodeLookup
```